# Neo4j multilabel modes and query performance

Tags: neo4j, cypher, query-optimization

Let's say I have a Decision base node with a defined ID:

```
@NodeEntity
public class Decision {

    @Id
    @Index(unique = true)
    private Long id;

}
```

I have defined a `UNIQUE INDEX on Decision.id`.

Additionally, I have two nodes derived from Decision:

```
@NodeEntity
public class Profile extends Decision {
}

@NodeEntity
public class Notification extends Decision{
}
```

Let's consider a scenario where I have `1000 Profiles` in my database and `1 billion Notifications`. Will querying Profiles by a Cypher query be significantly affected by the presence of 1 billion Notification nodes because they share the same common label 'Decision'?

Should I also add a UNIQUE INDEX on 'Profile.id' and 'Notification.id,' even if they inherit it from the 'Decision' node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A uniqueness constraint creates a RANGE index. RANGE indexes internally use the B+ tree algorithm, which have O(log n) complexity.

`log2` of 1K is about 10, and `log2` of 1G is about 30. It is up to you to decide whether a factor of 3 is significant enough to warrant creating another index. Creating an extra index for only 1K nodes should not take up much storage, so that should not be a concern. You may want to try it to see if it is worth it.

Comment: Agreed. Nothing beats an experiment to test what works best!!